# Expositions of Gross and Zagier's On Singular Moduli

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves

I'm looking for a good exposition of Gross-Zagier's classic paper *On Singular Moduli*, along the lines of what is written [here](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewarner/notes/GrossZagier.pdf), except for the algebraic proof rather than the analytic one.

Basically, I'm wondering if anyone who has spent the time going through the paper carefully, and finding references for the various facts left to the reader, has collected those references into a sketch that could be a useful complement to reading the paper itself. Alternatively, perhaps there is a well-written overview in a survey article, or in the Bulletin, or something along those lines?

If anyone knows of anything useful, please let me know!